# How to get my device recognized as an HID device?

Tags: drivers, usb, udev, hid

I'm trying to get a USB HID device to work in Ubuntu, but can't seem to get it to work at all. It is a USB HID device, and shows up as such in dmesg:

```
[ 2236.277518] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
[ 2236.429224] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0b6a, idProduct=5346
[ 2236.429230] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2236.429234] usb 1-1: Product: Rejoyce 
[ 2236.429237] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: REHABTRONICS
[ 2236.429240] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 0000
[ 2758.828284] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 17
[ 2760.813658] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[ 2760.966827] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0b6a, idProduct=5346
[ 2760.966829] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2760.966830] usb 1-1: Product: Rejoyce 
[ 2760.966832] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: REHABTRONICS
[ 2760.966832] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 0000
```

but the generic-hid driver isn't loaded, and nothing new shows up under `/dev/hidraw*`

Running `lsusb` on the device (which *does* show up under `/dev/bus/usb/001/`) gives:

```
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 0b6a:5346 Maxim Integrated Products 
Device Descriptor:
bLength                18
bDescriptorType         1
bcdUSB               2.00
bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
bDeviceSubClass       255 Vendor Specific Subclass
bDeviceProtocol       255 Vendor Specific Protocol
bMaxPacketSize0        64
idVendor           0x0b6a Maxim Integrated Products
idProduct          0x5346 
bcdDevice            0.01
iManufacturer           1 REHABTRONICS
iProduct                2 Rejoyce 
iSerial                 3 0000
bNumConfigurations      1
Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           41
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
    (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              450mA
    Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         4
    bInterfaceNumber        0
    bAlternateSetting       0
    bNumEndpoints           2
    bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
    bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
    bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
    iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        33
        bcdHID               1.10
        bCountryCode            0 Not supported
        bNumDescriptors         1
        bDescriptorType        34 Report
        wDescriptorLength      34
        Report Descriptor: (length is 34)
            Item(Global): Usage Page, data= [ 0xa0 0xff ] 65440
                            (null)
            Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
                            (null)
            Item(Main  ): Collection, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
                            Application
            Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x02 ] 2
                            (null)
            Item(Global): Logical Minimum, data= [ 0x00 ] 0
            Item(Global): Logical Maximum, data= [ 0xff 0x00 ] 255
            Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x08 ] 8
            Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x20 ] 32
            Item(Main  ): Input, data= [ 0x02 ] 2
                            Data Variable Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                            Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
            Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x03 ] 3
                            (null)
            Item(Global): Logical Minimum, data= [ 0x00 ] 0
            Item(Global): Logical Maximum, data= [ 0xff 0x00 ] 255
            Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x08 ] 8
            Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x08 ] 8
            Item(Main  ): Output, data= [ 0x02 ] 2
                            Data Variable Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                            Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
            Item(Main  ): End Collection, data=none
    Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
        Transfer Type            Interrupt
        Synch Type               None
        Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval              16
    Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
        Transfer Type            Interrupt
        Synch Type               None
        Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval              16
Device Status:     0x0000
(Bus Powered)
```

Which again implies a USB HID device.

`udevadm info /dev/bus/usb/001/018` gives:

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1
N: bus/usb/001/018
E: BUSNUM=001
E: DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/018
E: DEVNUM=018
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1
E: DEVTYPE=usb_device
E: DRIVER=usb
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_MODEL=Rejoyce
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Rejoyce\x20
E: ID_MODEL_ID=5346
E: ID_REVISION=0001
E: ID_SERIAL=REHABTRONICS_Rejoyce_0000
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=0000
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030000:
E: ID_VENDOR=REHABTRONICS
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=REHABTRONICS
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Maxim Integrated Products
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0b6a
E: MAJOR=189
E: MINOR=17
E: PRODUCT=b6a/5346/1
E: SUBSYSTEM=usb
E: TYPE=255/255/255
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=2760968874
```

I did create a udev rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-hid.rules` with the contents (and variations on this):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0b6a", MODE="0666"
KERNEL=="hidraw*", ATTRS{busnum}=="001", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0b6a", MODE="0666"
```

But that doesn't seem to have done anything (even after reloading with `udevadm control --reload-rules` *and* rebooting).

I'm at a complete loss on what to do here, other HID devices work just fine (for example, unplugging and plugging my keyboard gives the following in dmesg:)

```
[ 3329.994265] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 11
[ 3332.283514] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[ 3332.432917] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2516, idProduct=0047
[ 3332.432923] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 3332.432927] usb 1-2: Product: MasterKeys Pro L White
[ 3332.432931] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Cooler Master Technology Inc.
[ 3332.434839] input: Cooler Master Technology Inc. MasterKeys Pro L White as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:2516:0047.0011/input/input30
[ 3332.491698] hid-generic 0003:2516:0047.0011: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Cooler Master Technology Inc. MasterKeys Pro L White] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[ 3332.492863] hid-generic 0003:2516:0047.0012: hiddev1,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [Cooler Master Technology Inc. MasterKeys Pro L White] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input1
[ 3332.494695] input: Cooler Master Technology Inc. MasterKeys Pro L White as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:2516:0047.0013/input/input31
[ 3332.555443] hid-generic 0003:2516:0047.0013: input,hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Cooler Master Technology Inc. MasterKeys Pro L White] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input2
```

Any advice on how to get this device recognized as an HID device?

Thanks!

Comment: Your first `dmesg` doesn't say that it's an USB device. The USB descriptor does, though. Module loading is not controlled by `udev`, it's controlled by the module itself. First step is to do `modinfo hid-generic`, and look at the alias pattern of your version of it, then compare it with the USB descriptor and figure out why it doesn't trigger. If that yields nothing, next step would be to look at the kernel sources and find out if the HID detection is done elsewhere as well.

Comment: Thanks! Running that I get: `alias: hid:b*g0001v*p*` while the modalias file in the /sys descriptor gives `usb:v0B6Ap5346d0001dcFFdscFFdpFFic03isc00ip00in00` so it seems like the device isn't reporting as a USB HID device then?

Comment: My USB HID devices have two `modalias` files, one of type `usb` under the USB path, and one of type `hid` under an additional `aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd` directory. If your device doesn't have the latter, then guess: the kernel doesn't like the HID descriptor for some reason (the many `null` values in `lsub -v` are suspicious), and decides it's not a valid HID device, and therefore doesn't load `hid-generic`. Kernel HID parser is in `drivers/hid/hid-core.c`. Maybe one can enable debugging for the USB/HID system somehow, and see where it hiccups.

Comment: Yea, there is only the one `modalias` and nothing like `aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd`. I wouldn't be terribly surprised if the device isn't a perfect HID spec device, though it does seem to work on Windows. Thanks, I'll look into things!